# .htaccess rewrite page to page.php

Tags: .htaccess

It is hassle to rewrite every page using

```
RewriteRule ^login$  login.php [L,NC]
```

So I am looking for a RewriteRule that will produce someting like

```
page1 to page1.php
page2 to page2.php
page3 to page3.php

and so on.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should maybe take a closer look at RewriteRules. In your case the simple solution is:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php [L,NC]
```

**EDIT:** Added RewriteCond from comments

Comment: I already tried but produces page.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php

Comment: sry. What endings do your page have?

Comment: the real file extension is .php and im linking the page using site.com/page instead of site.com/page.php

Comment: Sry lunch break. Your coorect. RewriteCond is missing.